# Avoid joins or not?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

Imagine you have a table POSTS with 50 million posts. This table has:

```
ID, POST, CATEGORY_ID
1, "Hello world", 2
```

And then you have a CATEGORIES table with:

```
ID, CATEGORY_NAME
1, "Football"
2, "Baseball"
```

On the website, you list these posts in ORDER DESC, showing the post and the category name using a join.

```
[Baseball]
Hello World!
```

I'm thinking on adding (when someone create a new post) the CATEGORY_NAME column to the POSTS table in order to avoid having to make that JOIN everytime I get a visit.

In order of performance, is a good idea? Imagine you have 10.000.000 visitors daily (hopefully :))

On the other hand, I would like to know what DB engine you consider better for it, mysql? mariadb? mongodb?

EDIT:

Imagine a more real scenario: I need 3 joins to show POST + CATEGORY + USER_NAME.

```
POSTS: 50 million rows
CATEGORIES: 100 rows
USERS: 10 million rows
```

Option A) Join between the 3 tables to show:

```
[Baseball]
Hello World
- By John
```

Option B) Adding 2 columns (CAT_NAME, USER_NAME) varchar(25) to POSTS table in order to avoid the join.

Comment: "I'm thinking on adding (when someone create a new post) the CATEGORY_NAME column to the POSTS table in order to avoid having to make that JOIN everytime I get a visit.." - that would be termed 'denormalisation' - unless you have measured a performance problem don't do it.

Comment: The category table sounds to be quite small, so the performance impact should be minimal (basically in-memory hash lookup).  If there is a problem, I'd investigate caching (in particular because category names probably very rarely change) before denormalization.

Comment: But in theory it should be faster with high traffic, right? I update main post with a second scenario.

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, no.

Comment: @Juhana You can explain your answer?

Comment: Mitch Wheat and Thilo have already explained it. *"unless you have measured a performance problem don't do it."* *"The category table sounds to be quite small, so the performance impact should be minimal (basically in-memory hash lookup)."* You're micro-optimizing.

Comment: In practice increasing the size of each row reduces the number of rows that can fit into a page on disk, increasing the number of pages the DBMS has to load and process.  Rather than worry about joins, use EXPLAIN to make sure your tables are properly indexed for the actual queries you're running.

Comment: The site is still under development, I opened this Question because I have doubts about how to do this. Seem that I should use joins then...

Answer (score 0):

Keep things normalized.

The cost of the `JOIN` is less than the cost caused by having a plumper table.  Currently (small amount of data) you cannot see much performance difference.  When the tables are too big to cache in RAM, the performance benefit of normalization will shine.